# Android questions: LogCat

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Out of my experience, if the topic starter complained about some problems and DID NOT post his LogCat trace, the 1st comment looks usually so: `post your logcat`

Hence the suggestion, we should enforce it for android questions to post the logcat so that community can help faster

Comment: Agreed! I mentioned this somewhere but it didn't seem to go anywhere. I will see if I can find it. Though, I think there is a lot to consider because a lot of questions (not most) will not need the stacktrace. I'm not sure we can really force them to post it but some other way to express that they need it.

Comment: Logcats are useful only in case of questions about exceptions (to see the stacktrace). Current way is fine IMO. Those are generally low-quality homework questions where OP lacks debugging skill.

Comment: no no, not all questions are EXPLICIT about exceptions >). Most of them sound like: "My first/sample app crashes. Why?". Although for 90% of them only the logcat posted makes the analysis valid.

Comment: First sample app crashed due to xyx exception (ClassCastException, NullPointerException etc etc etc). Crash = exception.

Comment: You know that and I know that, and we would definitely post our logcats straight away. But for majority of other not so experienced developers and SO users it's absolutely not clear

Comment: simply scan the android topics and see that pattern yourself

Comment: I can't support this as written. What would you do if you have a question that doesn't require LogCat to answer? We can't *force* people to post it on every Android question just because some require it. It would be better to come up with a way to detect (based on tags, keywords, code, etc.) when a LogCat is probably needed, then display a suggestion to post it.

Comment: we should not really force it, we can offer a container for posting the logcat and/or display the confirm dialog `are you sure, you want to post the question w/o logcat?` Not sure, what is better in terms of how SO-engine is workgin...

Comment: We now have the ability to display non-blocking warnings / suggestions to folks based on keywords in their post - this would make an excellent test-case for this feature, if there are some good (reasonably unambiguous) indicators. cc @Bill

Comment: @Shog9 This sounds like it could be an interesting ML project. I'd start by looking at Android questions that have been edited to include LogCat to see what they had in common pre-edit.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Almost all Android questions are because of a crash. I think that a warning as Shog suggests would be perfect. (if you don't believe me, browse the recent [tag:android] questions)

Comment: @hichris123 Crash questions which **don't** include a logcat in original version have low quality. Non-logcat Android questions are the ones that survive longer and are answerable (about API's, layouts, maps, animations). Adding logcat hints won't make much diff IMO. Will gather data and post an elaborate answer here later today.

Comment: Those OP who don't include an exception logcat, lack minimal understanding of exception handling, and all the answers are always the same - use try-catch..handle your exception..add null-check..they all get closed as dupes or unclear

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion you have a valid point (almost) on that they all get closed (but I wouldn't say all). However, we typically can't close them appropriately **without** the logcat as there could be many possibilities. There do exist questions which involve reading the logcat that are helpful questions.

Comment: Just keywords in the post or tags as well @shog? Usually a fairly clear indicator of a question that needs more info is one tagged SQL, but not with one of the RDBMS tags.

Comment: @hichris123: I'm not convinced that is true. While I don't systematically look for Android questions, it looks like I have answered 70 questions that had an Android tag. Among those 70, I can find only 1 that has the word "crash" in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Based off of [Bill's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267786/android-questions-logcat#comment72738_267786), I've decided to start some lists of things that the system could look for. If any of the selected items are in the body, title, or tags then pop up a window when the user tries to submit the question. Possibly say something like **:**

> Your post seems to be based off of an exception causing your app to crash. Please post the stacktrace/logcat to receive faster/more efficient help. If you don't know how to get your stacktrace, [please see this post for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461190/logcat-wont-show-up) or consult your IDE's documentation

There may be a better SO post showing various ways of obtaining the stacktrace but I just picked that one. I don't know how feasible any of this is, but it's a start **:**

**Keywords**

1. Crash
2. Exception
3. Unfortunately application stopped unexpectedly
4. NullPointerException
5. Error
6. Not Responding
7. ANR

**Tags**

1. android
2. exception (maybe it can look to see if this word is anywhere in each tag to cover all of them)
3. nullpointerexception (in case #2 won't work)

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I thought it would be more inviting of edits if anyone had something to add. Should it not be? I've never actually created a CW before

Comment: I added a few keyword ideas, so I think a CW is a good idea.  I don't think anyone who's a problem would actually add the exception or the nullpointerexception tag.  Notice that 99% of the abusers are newbies.  The other 1% get the interesting exceptions and know enough to post it.

Comment: @GabeSechan until I posted this I would have agreed with you about the tags. However, I went through some random posts that needed a logcat but were lacking, and I had saw at least one that had the NPE tag. Also, I see posts all the time that say they have a NPE or whatever it may be and still don't post the stacktrace. So it would be good for those people.

Comment: I asked about CW because I don't know the usage either. I thought you know and could tell me :)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Ah, ok. I thought you were telling me it shouldn't be so I was confused. I marked it as CW because I know it's not a complete answer and I encourage others with good ideas to add to feel free to do so. This answer sums it up nicely, I think http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108136/what-is-community-wiki-for/108137#108137

Answer (score -4):

```
Patern.compile(forNullPointerException).matcher(useInput).start();
```

preliminary tagging :D i like the idea 1^UP

**EDIT:**

@CodeMagick proposal for preliminary tagging

userQuestion -> Matching Keywords (eg as MAP) - "auto Tagging feature "

call it how u want

then "u cann pick a cathegory within the specified range for example

1. Class:

   - Receiver
   - Service
   - AsyncTask

2 . Exceptions:

- NullPointer
- IllegalArgument
- etc

-> grouping common class of problems

many of common problems in various languages c<->java <->javascript

Comment: What?  This doesn't make any sense.